# Mobile Navbar Wordpress Mystile Theme Issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am having a issue with the navbar on the child theme using the Mystile theme. When on a mobile phone the nav bar turns into a square box that you click on to acess the navbar, for some reason it appears ontop of the logo, I just can't figure out or get any CSS to make it go to its own line. I am hoping someone can help here.
Website: http://test.cyberglide.co.uk

Comment: where you want display square box? below logo?

Comment: hello, yea i tried adding a div tag to it as well and set the css to clear both and that dident work as well.

Comment: Try to set a width of `logo` id 70% and `nav-toggle` is 25% in the media query for responsiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Custom CSS plugin (asking you to install plugin because it overrides all other CSS) and insert this CSS. You can use other methods to override all other conflicting CSS sheets.

Be sure to include media queries for Mobile views.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:43.75em) { 
  #header #logo {
  float: none;
  display: block;
}
  #header .nav-toggle {
      position: relative !important;
      display: inline;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks i had to do the width suggested above as well, but the button is not covering the menu text still, have you any ideas?

Comment: i tried that azmat but the button still does not cover the text so the button is too small, as only half the menu title is in the button

Comment: @MichaelRooks can you send me wp-admin credentials to have a look?

Comment: thank you so much for all your help i am really greatful, yea no problem i moved it to a new subdomain http://beta.cyberglide.co.uk so i can try figure it out without missing with the original. Just trying to figure out how to pm you credentials on this site, never messaged on here.

Comment: @MichaelRooks you can send an email to mehmood.azmat@gmail.com

Comment: @MichaelRooks How about now?